# AutoComplete TextBox in WPF bind IEnumerable<String>

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, ienumerable

I was find a library at https://github.com/Nimgoble/WPFTextBoxAutoComplete/

but I stuck at step 3

Create a textbox and bind the "AutoCompleteItemsSource" to a collection of IEnumerable

I try the tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netframework-4.8

but it still doesn't work, I don't know where is the problem

and here is my code

https://github.com/BudinMilk/textbox_autocomplete/tree/master/textbox_autocomplete

Thank you!

Comment: Could you describe in detail what your problem is?

Comment: I am a C# beginner and like to implement textbox autocomplete function, I searching simple or easy way to implement, forget me my English is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through your code try these changes out and I think it'll work for you.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
            TestItems = new ObservableCollection<string>()
            {
                "Apple",
                "Banana",
                "Carrot",
                "Dog",
                "Elderberry",
                "Fruit",
                "Grapes",
                "Honey",
                "Iron"
            };
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {   
            Person[] peopleArray = new Person[3]
            {
                new Person("John"),
                new Person("Jim"),
                new Person("Sue"),
            };

            People peopleList = new People(peopleArray);
            foreach (Person p in peopleList)
                Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    private ObservableCollection<string> testItems ;
    public ObservableCollection<string> TestItems 
    {
        get { return testItems; }
        set
        {
            testItems= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TestItems");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler == null) return;
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
 }
```